# Create a static array that is accessible to all instances

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a static array to hold a two linked lists that will hold terms of two different polynomials. The Term class has two int values that represent the Coefficient and Exponent. My problem is everytime a new "Polynomial" it creates a new instance of the Array. I tried to make the array static but it gives me a compiler error a you cannot pass the modifer. My code is below. thanks for the help:

```
public class LinkedListInArrayPolynomial implements PolynomialInterface 
{

public boolean isFirst = true;
public Term firstTerm;
public int currentFree = 0;
Term[] PolynomialArray = new Term[100];
static class Term {
    public int coef;
    public int exp;

    public Term next;

    public Term(int coefIntput, int expInput) {
        this.coef = coefIntput;
        this.exp = expInput;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "Coef is " + this.coef + " Exp is " + this.exp;
        return output;
    }

}

public void addToArray(Term term) {
    int marker = 0;
    boolean written = false;

    while (written = false) {
        if (PolynomialArray[marker] == null) {
            PolynomialArray[marker] = term;
            term.next = firstTerm;
            this.firstTerm = term;
            written = true;
        } else {
            marker++;
        }
    }
}

public LinkedListInArrayPolynomial() {
    firstTerm = null;
}

public LinkedListInArrayPolynomial(String input) {


    boolean FirstElementPos = true;
    int exponent;
    int coef;
    String tempExp = null;
    if (input.charAt(0) == '-') {
        input = input.substring(1);
        FirstElementPos = false;
    }

    String inputPolynomial = input.replaceAll("-", "+-");
    String[] splitTerms = inputPolynomial.split("\\+");

    for (int i = 0; i < splitTerms.length; i++) {
        String tempTerm = splitTerms[i];

        boolean tempPos;
        tempPos = true;
        if (tempTerm.contains("-")) {
            tempTerm = tempTerm.substring(1);

            tempPos = false;
        }
        int IndexOfexponent = tempTerm.indexOf('^');

        if (IndexOfexponent == -1) {
            if (tempTerm.indexOf('x') == -1) {
                exponent = 0;
            } else {
                exponent = 1;
            }

        } else {
            tempExp = tempTerm.substring(IndexOfexponent + 1);
            exponent = Integer.parseInt(tempExp);

        }

        String tempTermNoCarrot = tempTerm.replaceAll("\\^" + tempExp, "");
        String tempCoef = tempTermNoCarrot.replaceAll("x", "");

        coef = Integer.parseInt(tempCoef);

        if (tempPos == false || FirstElementPos == false) {
            coef = (coef * -1);
            tempPos = true;
            FirstElementPos = true;
        }
        Term newTerm = new Term(coef, exponent);
        System.out.println("Before insert");
        System.out.println(newTerm);
        PolynomialArray[currentFree] = newTerm;
        System.out.println("After insert");
        System.out.println(PolynomialArray[currentFree]
                + " At PolynomialArray[" + currentFree + "]");
        currentFree++;

        // this.addToArray(newTerm);

    }

}

public String toString() {
    String tempresult = "";
    Term current = firstTerm;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.exp == 0) {
            tempresult += "+";
            tempresult += current.coef;

        } else {
            tempresult += "+";
            tempresult += current.coef;
            tempresult += "x^";
            tempresult += current.exp;

        }
        current = current.next;

    }

    tempresult = tempresult.replaceAll("\\^0", "");
    tempresult = tempresult.replaceAll("\\+-", "-");
    // System.out.println(" at 0 " + PolynomialArray[0].coef);
    System.out.println("tempresult before processing: " + tempresult);
    PolynomialInterface processingResult = new ArrayWithExponentAsIndexPolynomial(
            tempresult);
    return processingResult.toString();

}

@Override
public PolynomialInterface add(PolynomialInterface other) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public PolynomialInterface subtract(PolynomialInterface other) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void readPolynomial() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

**Please note I have multiple System.out.print lines that are there for debugging purposes.

Comment: Which line is giving the compile time error if you make the array static??? Can you copy and paste the exact error message here?

Comment: Mutable global (i.e. `static`) variables are a great evil and should be avoided at all costs. This is unrelated to `static class`, which is often better to just put the class at top level instead.

Comment: Im not getting an error. Im having trouble creating an array that can be used by multiple instances of the same class. Right now, each instance is using its own array

Comment: No, we mean what is the error you are getting when making the array static